# Make a png image transparent

Tags: vb.net, winforms, graphics, bitmap, transparency

I have a `PictureBox` added to my `Panel1` with `Panel1.Controls.Add(pb)`, and I have tried to make my `.png` picture transparent.
I have tried with `Color.Transparent` and with `System.Drawing.Color.Transparent`, but when I add the `PictureBox` to my `Panel`, I can not make it transparent.

And also I'm not able to bring to the front of the others images.

This is my code.

```
Private Function molduraint()

    Dim pb As New PictureBox

    pb.BringToFront()
    pb.ImageLocation = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage

    Panel1.Controls.Add(pb)

    pb.Location = New Point(txtValueX.Text, txtValueY.Text)
    If txtValueX.Text = 0 Or txtValueY.Text = 0 Then
        pb.Location = New Point(300, 172)
    End If

    pb.Visible = True
    pb.Size = New Size(TrackBar1.Value, TrackBar2.Value)
    pb.Image = PictureBox1.Image

End Function
```

Comment: Depending on your context, you could draw the images directly on the panel. This way, you have one container only and you can preserve the images transparency.

Comment: @Jimi Tank you for replay can you please have a kind to show an example how to do it

Comment: Sure. I'll put something together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you probably know, `WinForms` controls are not exactly designed to support true transparency (except `Forms`, those can be actually transparent).

`Bitmaps`, on the other hand, support transparency.
If you create a `Bitmap` object using an image format that supports an Alpha Channel, like a `.png` bitmap, you can draw that image preserving its transparency.

The first thing to do is to create an object that can be used to reference each `Bitmap` we want to draw, so we can keep track of them.
Since you want to be able to specify position and size of these objects, those are two of the properties that the object must have. I'm adding some more that can be helpful here.

```
Public Class BitmapObject
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Image As Bitmap
    Public Property Position As Point
    Public Property Size As Size
    Public Property Order As Integer
End Class
```

The property `Name` will be the name of source file and `Order` will reference the z-order position of the `Bitmap` in relation to the other `Bitmaps` drawn inside a container.
All the `Bitmaps` will be grouped using a List of `Bitmap` objects, so we can summon them using the List Index or one of the properties.

```
Public MyBitmaps As List(Of BitmapObject) = New List(Of BitmapObject)
```

As for the drawing surface (canvas), we can use the `Form` itself, a `PictureBox` or a `Panel` (because they're - more or less - just surfaces). I prefer a `Panel`, it's lightweight, it can host other controls and can be moved around if needed.

If you want to draw on a control, you just need to subscribe its `Paint()` event and raise it calling the control's `Invalidate()` method.

```
Private Sub Panel1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Panel1.Paint
    If MyBitmaps.Count > 0 Then
        MyBitmaps.OrderBy(Function(item) item.Order).
            Select(Function(item)
                       e.Graphics.DrawImage(item.Image, New Rectangle(item.Position, item.Size))
                       Return item
                   End Function).ToList()
    End If
End Sub
```

To add a `Bitmap` to the `List(Of BitmapObject)`, since you want to use an `OpenFileDialog` to let the user select a `Bitmap`, we assign this functionality to a `Button` and when the `Bitmap` is selected, a new `BitmapObject` is created and appended to the List.

```
Private Sub btnOpenFile_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOpenFile.Click

    Dim fd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
    fd.InitialDirectory = "[Images Path]"
    Dim dr As DialogResult = fd.ShowDialog()

    If dr = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim BitmapName As String = New FileInfo(fd.FileName).Name

        Using tmpBitmap As Bitmap = New Bitmap(fd.FileName)
            MyBitmaps.Add(New BitmapObject With {
                          .Image = New Bitmap(tmpBitmap),
                          .Position = New Point(Integer.Parse(TextBox1.Text), Integer.Parse(TextBox2.Text)),
                          .Size = New Size(tmpBitmap.Height, tmpBitmap.Width),
                          .Order = MyBitmaps.Count,
                          .Name = BitmapName})

            ComboBox1.Items.Add(BitmapName)
            ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = MyBitmaps.Count - 1
            TrackBar1.Value = tmpBitmap.Height
            TrackBar2.Value = tmpBitmap.Width
            Panel1.Invalidate()
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

This is the result: ([Full source code in PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/Pi9djpFf))

[image]

Comment: Tank You For The Great Help well in fact i have a few errors on this code the first is The type PaintForm is made of several partial classes in the same file.

Comment: the second is Error 1 'Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)' has multiple definitions with identical signatures. C:\Users\Utilizador\Desktop\memebuilder2_1 Code\gLabel\PaintForm.Designer.vb 7 29

Comment: the 3 is Error 2 'Private Sub InitializeComponent()' has multiple definitions with identical signatures. C:\Users\Utilizador\Desktop\memebuilder2_1 Code\gLabel\PaintForm.Designer.vb 24 17

Comment: 4 is Error 3 'OrderBy' is not a member of 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of gLabel.PaintForm.BitmapObject)'. C:\Users\Utilizador\Desktop\memebuilder2_1 Code\gLabel\PaintForm.vb 42 13

Comment: 5Error 5 'components' is already declared as 'Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer' in this class. C:\Users\Utilizador\Desktop\memebuilder2_1 Code\gLabel\PaintForm.vb 110 13

Comment: @bluemoon odd   Have you noticed that the PasteBin code is in fact a Form, usually a partial class?. You should create a new, empty Form, then substitute all its pre-defined code with the code you find in PasteBin, following the Class declaration parts. Anyway, I'll see if I can make it easier to paste in, maybe adding some notes.

Comment: @bluemoon odd   Allright. PasteBin code updated. I wrote some instruction on how to paste that code inside a new Form. Tested an working. Ping me if you need some help.

Comment: Real Tank You For The Great Help , I have Done Like You Say And Its Works Perfect , ok i thing its out of topic but it is possible to do the same with the text part?

Comment: @bluemoon odd  Yes, of course. Use the [Graphics.DrawString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring(v=vs.110).aspx) in the `Paint()` event of the Panel to draw some text on it. Maybe post a new specific question for this, if have troubles with it (without using the code you found here as a source).