# How Can Resize a Bitmap

Tags: c#

I found a code to overlay pictures, really is a bitmap, but also I would like to resize both of the bitmap specially the overlay bitmap (  `OverlayBitmap = new Bitmap(ofdFile.FileName);`)
btw this does nothing

```
public static Bitmap ResizeImage(Bitmap imgToResize, Size size)
{
    try
    {
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(size.Width, size.Height);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)b))
        {
            g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            g.DrawImage(imgToResize, 0, 0, size.Width, size.Height);
        }
        return b;
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bitmap could not be resized");
        return imgToResize;
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Size = new Size(30, 30);

    ResizeImage(OverlayBitmap,  Size);
}
```

the code with example is here.

http://csharphelper.com/blog/2016/11/overlay-images-in-c/

I try myself this, with no success.

```
Size = new Size(30, 30);
ResizeImage(OverlayBitmap,  Size);
```

the complete code is here:

```
private void mnuFileExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Close();
}

// The background image.
private Bitmap BackgroundBitmap = null;

// The overlay image.
private Bitmap OverlayBitmap = null;

// The current combined image.
private Bitmap CombinedBitmap = null;

// The location of the overlay image.
private Point OverlayLocation = new Point(0, 0);

// Reduce flicker.
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoubleBuffered = true;
}

// Let the user open a file.
private void mnuFileOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ofdFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        try
        {
            // Open the file.
            BackgroundBitmap = new Bitmap(ofdFile.FileName);
            picImage.Image = BackgroundBitmap;
            picImage.Visible = true;
            ClientSize = new Size(
                picImage.Right + picImage.Left,
                picImage.Bottom + picImage.Left);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error opening file.\n" + ex.Message,
                "Open Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}

// Load the overlay image.
private void mnuFileOverlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ofdFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        try
        {
            // Open the file.
            OverlayBitmap = new Bitmap(ofdFile.FileName);
            picImage.Cursor = Cursors.Cross;

            // Display the combined image.
            ShowCombinedImage();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error opening file.\n" + ex.Message,
                "Open Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}

// Display the combined image.
private void ShowCombinedImage()
{
    // If there's no background image, do nothing.
    if (BackgroundBitmap == null) return;

    // Copy the background.
    CombinedBitmap = new Bitmap(BackgroundBitmap);

    // Add the overlay.
    if (OverlayBitmap != null)
    {
        using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(CombinedBitmap))
        {
            gr.DrawImage(OverlayBitmap, OverlayLocation);
        }
    }

    // Display the result.
    picImage.Image = CombinedBitmap;
}

// Drag the overlay image.
private void picImage_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (OverlayBitmap == null) return;
    OverlayLocation = new Point(
        e.X - OverlayBitmap.Width / 2,
        e.Y - OverlayBitmap.Height / 2);
    ShowCombinedImage();
}

// Finish dragging the overlay image.
private void picImage_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (OverlayBitmap == null) return;
    OverlayBitmap = null;
    picImage.Cursor = Cursors.Default;

    // Make the overlay permanent.
    BackgroundBitmap = CombinedBitmap;
}

// Save the current result image.
private void mnuFileSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CombinedBitmap == null) return;
    if (sfdFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        SaveBitmapUsingExtension(CombinedBitmap, sfdFile.FileName);
    }
}

// Save the file with the appropriate format.
// Throw a NotSupportedException if the file
// has an unknown extension.
public void SaveBitmapUsingExtension(Bitmap bm, string filename)
{
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(filename);
    switch (extension.ToLower())
    {
        case ".bmp":
            bm.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            break;
        case ".exif":
            bm.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Exif);
            break;
        case ".gif":
            bm.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Gif);
            break;
        case ".jpg":
        case ".jpeg":
            bm.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            break;
        case ".png":
            bm.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Png);
            break;
        case ".tif":
        case ".tiff":
            bm.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Tiff);
            break;
        default:
            throw new NotSupportedException(
                "Unknown file extension " + extension);
    }
}

private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resize bitmap image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839358/resize-bitmap-image)

Comment: The resize method returns a Bitmap (btw, with, possibly, a different Dpi resolution and `PixelFormat`). You need to get that Bitmap and to something with it: `Bitmap newBitmap = ResizeImage(OverlayBitmap,  Size);`. Then, draw the resized Bitmap (which needs to be a `PNG` image) over another Image in a specific location. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50082351/make-a-png-image-transparent?answertab=active#tab-top). (using `VB.Net` here, but the process is exactly the same). Also, you're leaking Graphics resources everywhere.