# Draw a circle over a line

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to draw a circle over a line.

I am using `e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, x1, y1, x2, y2);` to draw line and `e.Graphics.DrawArc(greenPen, rect1, 0, 360);` to draw the circle.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7BeO.png)  is output of my program. I want that green circle to be over the black line.

Comment: If you draw the circles _after_ you draw the lines, they will appear on top of the lines. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, that's what i want. But there is no method like BringToFront or something like? Because that's the flow of my program, and to draw them after the lines means major modification of code.

Comment: There isn't a bringtofront, because these things dont exist on the bitmap as objects that can be moved around and re-ordered. When they're drawn onto the bitmap they just color the pixels of the bitmap whatever color at the time of the draw. They have become part of the single layer of colored pixels that makes up the image. If you didn't get what I mean, open MS PAINT and draw 3 lines, now try to select the first one (you can't, the image is jsut an array of pixels that are set a color and that's it, you're done).

Comment: Ok then. I have to modify the order of drawing . Thanks

Comment: You might be able to cheat a bit, if you can find some way to attach an extension to the Graphics or encapsulate it in another class(tha your program will use instead), and provide new methods for drawarc/drawline for your program to use, so that it keeps a list of every arc it's been asked to draw, and then every time a line is drawn, redraw all the arcs too (naive) or redraw any arc that is on the line (harder to code)

Comment: You can use layers using bitmaps. So, a bitmap for the lines and a bitmap for the circles. At the end draw the lines bitmap to the form first, and then the circles. This may (or may not) be minimal change to your current code.

Comment: [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50083671/7444103) of graphics objects drawn using a helper class that allows to define a z-order. You can *BringToFront* any of the objects at any time (VB.Net code this one, but you can derive the logic, it's just a specialized class that provides an *order* property).

Comment: Have you tried keeping track of the coordinates of the circles in an array or map and then redraw them at the end?

Comment: SomeNerdAtWork that's what C.Evenhuis said and finally, after a couple of hours, i accomplished to draw circles after lines and them appear on top.

Comment: There are some good ideas over here. I'll try implement them to see how them works. Thank you guys .

Comment: _to draw them after the lines means major modification of code_ Which means that your code is badly structuted. Time for a rewrite!